# Cordova renders only the index.html content

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to compile an app which works fine when I run `ionic serve` for android.

However when I open on compiled apk, it shows a blank page. The config.xml is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.airvend532374" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

I have no idea how to find out if there're any javascript or file loading problems. Is there something I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can debug your cordova app running on your phone like so:

1. plug your phone to your computer with usb cable (be sure to have developper mode enabled in your phone configuration)
2. in your chrome browser, navigate this url: chrome://inspect

you should see debugging info about your cordova app & a button "inspect".

-> click this button, this will open chrome debugging console for your cordova browser application

1. run command "cordova run android"

now you can check "console" or "network" tabs and debug your app

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/48/how-to-debug-a-cordova-app-on-your-device-with-google-chrome) that details about steps to debug Cordova app in device using google chrome.

Also I suggest you to first try out your code in barebone Cordova project instead of ionic and test the same in browser platform to ensure that basic screen works in browser before porting the app to device. As per my experience browser platform is easy to test and debug issues.